# I want to retur or echo some code to display a jw player with the wordpress (add_before_content)

Tags: wordpress

I have edited the wordpress functions file to include the function add_before_content .

This gives me a return / echo area, i an in need of getting some code inside there. I have tried numerous times but i keep getting syntax errors. Could anyone help me out at all?

Pastebin:   http://pastebin.com/0vyJw712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping you mean you edited your *themes* functions.php file, not the functions.php file in the core of wordpress.

In any case, first thing glaring at me is some missing quotes. in your add_filter().

```
add_filter('the_content', 'add_before_content');
```